# Strange code construction for ADODB.Connection Open

Tags: asp-classic, ado

We're reviewing the code of Classic ASP application.
In the code that we're reviewing we see the following string:

```
Dim con as new ADODB.Connection
con.Open "SomeName"
...
```

The project ASP files are stored in the project folder root and the App_Data contains the file SomeName.mdb

We didn't get any guidelines about any additional data sources set up or some application settings, and when the con.Open "SomeName" is called - it crashes.
What should be done so the con.Open "SomeName" would actually open the \App_Data\SomeName.mdb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that `SomeName` is [an ODBC data source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms807027.aspx#workshp2_topic1).

Try replacing it with:

`"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=App_Data\SomeName.mdb;"`

Comment: Yes, that's what it was - the "SomeName" was a data source. We just never used such "default" behavior.

Comment: @Anders You should recommend using an OLE DB connection string and not the ODBC connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Got it. If you will create the DSN with such name "SomeThing", the con.Open "SomeThing" will normally find it.